# Codename one Border Issue

Tags: codenameone

In Creating the custom table, followed these steps,

```
if(row < 0)
{
  cell.getAllStyles().setPadding(1, 1, 5,5);
  cell.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEmpty(), true);
}
```

I tried to remove the border of the first row using the above code but its not working as i expected but tried to change the font color using

```
cell.getAllStyles().setFgcolor(ColorUtil.Blue);
```

Above code works fine ? can you help me out to slove this issue ...

Answer (score 1):

Lose the `true` parameter in your `setBorder()` call.  E.g.

```
cell.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved achieved it through

```
  table.setInnerBorderMode(Table.INNER_BORDERS_ROWS);
```

that removes column border and border only the row